# Procurar com um valor nulo, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

sou iniciante em programação  e estou tentando buscar uma coisa nova, no caso, eu tenho dois campos selects que informam pra minha pesquisa os valores, porém eu gostaria que a pesquisa pudesse ser feita mesmo que um campo seja nulo

Esse é o código do request

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            $id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
            $id_sub_categoria = $_POST['id_sub_categoria'];
            $pagina = 1;
            $_SESSION['id_categoria'] = $id_categoria;
            $_SESSION['id_sub_categoria'] = $id_sub_categoria;
```

E no caso esse é query executada

```
            $result_empresas = ("SELECT * FROM clientes 
                                WHERE categoria_id = '$id_categoria' AND subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' 
                                OR categoria_id = '$id_categoria' AND subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' IS NULL
                                OR subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' 
                                LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg");
```

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar

Comment: Mesmo assim, não entendi o porque disso, pois se tanto faz qualquer um estar setado ou for nulo, então porque o filtro ?

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes 
WHERE (
(categoria_id = '$id_categoria' AND subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria')
OR (categoria_id = '$id_categoria' AND subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' IS NULL)
OR (subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria')
) 
LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg
```

Ou:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes 
WHERE 
(
  (categoria_id = '$id_categoria' OR categoria_id IS NULL)
OR 
  (subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' OR subcategoria_id IS NULL)
) 
LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg
```

Quando trabalhar com `OR` precisa sempre ficar atento, se não os próximos atrapalham os anteriores.

Comment: ele me retornou, o seguinte erro, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clientes' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Quando estiver escrevedo selects com critérios dessa maneira, eu recomendo que use parênteses para deixar explícito as condições, para deixar uma leitura mais clara.

Acredito que seja isso o que vocÊ precisa:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clientes 
WHERE ( categoria_id = '$id_categoria' OR '$id_categoria' IS NULL ) AND 
    ( subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' OR '$id_sub_categoria' IS NULL ) AND
    ('$id_sub_categoria' IS NOT NULL OR '$id_categoria' IS NOT NULL)
LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg"
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele continua não gerando a table em seguida, só caso eu selecione as duas

Comment: Foi um erro meu dentro da database, muito obrigado amigo